# it happened a memory leaks when I getting image exif dictionary from a asset object using a static method,

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, exif

Following are the method an methods call tree that cause the memory leak

```
//get the exif info of image asset background
  @autoreleasepool {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray new];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        for (int i = 0; i < self.selectImageList.count; i++) {
            PFALAssetImageItemData *dataEntity = weakSelf.selectImageList[i];
            //getting the object usering an image asset

            ImageExifInfoEntity *imageExifEntity = [ImageExifInfoEntity getAlbumImageFromAsset:dataEntity.imageAsset imageOryder:i];

            LOG(@"%@",imageExifEntity.description);
            [weakSelf.dataSource addObject:imageExifEntity];
        }

        //back main thread update views
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
            [self hideHud];
        });
    });
}
```

In this code I want to creat ImageExifInfoEntity using a static method with an asset in a thread:

```
[ImageExifInfoEntity getAlbumImageFromAsset:dataEntity.imageAsset imageOryder:i];
```

In this method,it create an new object of ImageExifInfoEntity type,and get the exif Dictionary using a static method

```
+(ImageExifInfoEntity *)getAlbumImageFromAsset:(ALAsset *)asset category:(NSString *)category imageOryder:(NSInteger)imageOrder{
   ImageExifInfoEntity *albumImage = [ImageExifInfoEntity new];
   ..........
   albumImage.imageSize     = [UIImage imageSizeWithAlasset:asset];
   albumImage.exifDic      = [ImageExifInfoEntity getExifInfoFromAsset:asset] == nil ? @{}:[ImageExifInfoEntity getExifInfoFromAsset:asset];
   ..........
}
```

Finally,I get an exif dictionary using this method where the memory leak happed

```
+(NSDictionary *)getExifInfoFromAsset:(ALAsset *)asset {
   NSDictionary *_imageProperty;
   __weak ALAsset *tempAsset = asset;
   ALAssetRepresentation *representation = tempAsset.defaultRepresentation;
   uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(representation.size);
   NSError *error;
   NSUInteger length = [representation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0 length:representation.size error:&error];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:length];
   CGImageSourceRef cImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, NULL);
   CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(cImageSource, 0, NULL);
   _imageProperty = (__bridge_transfer  NSDictionary*)imageProperties;
   free(buffer);
   NSLog(@"image property: %@", _imageProperty);
   return _imageProperty;
```

}

here is the instrument analyze result

[call tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdggG.png)

[the final method that cause memory leaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwmHI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CGImageSourceCreateWithData()` is a creation function.

```
CGImageSourceRef cImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, NULL);
```

According to the CF memory rules, you have to release it with `CFRelease()`.

Comment: thanks,it works!but i wonder if the C Type transferred to OC Object should I release them.And another problem is the third part code line 4 `uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(representation.size);` ,why this code cause memory leak,thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure that the line 4 causes a memory leak? The buffer is freed at the end of the snippet.

Comment: yes,the instrument show the memory leak in the code `    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(representation.size);`,I don't know why

Comment: Me, too. :-) Please, check the value of buffer.

Answer (score 0):

replace `__bridge` with `__bridge_transfer` so that ARC will be in charge of freeing the memory

Comment: Here is not because of the CFDictionaryRef type object `imageProperties`,it  happened because of the [CGImageSourceRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageSourceCreateWithData) type variable didn't called by CFRelease() method ,but i wonder should I care about the C variable which was transfer to ObjectC type object,would it be release while the OC object in autorelease pool!

Comment: well you only have to call `CFRelease()` if you are using __bridge as far as i know because its not handled by ARC in that case. but the autorelease pool probably doesnt do much because there are no autoreleasing objects. ARC should handle the releasing automatically with proper reference counting

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `CFRelease(cImageSource);` to release the image source. See document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageSourceCreateWithData

> An image source. You are responsible for releasing this object using CFRelease.

Comment: yea,just because of missed the CFRelease method,but there still an memory leak I can't find the reason ,in the third pard of the code above located at line 4 ` uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(representation.size);`,this code cause a memory leak too.It just a OC object in autorelease pool and the malloc space was released after used , but it leaked